# Uniform approximation of $x^n$ by a degree $d$ polynomial: estimating the error 

Tags: approximation-theory

The answer to this question should be well known, but it's a hard question to search for online.

Suppose we want to approximate the function $x^n$ by a polynomial of degree $d$ in the $L_\infty$ norm on $[-1,1]$.  What is a good estimate of the error of the best approximator, in terms of $n$ and $d$?

I know this question was solved exactly by Chebyshev for $d = n-1$ (the error is $2^{-d}$ I think).  The range of interest for me is $\sqrt{n} \leq d \leq n$ and I don't mind log factors in the estimate.  Thus I would be happy to have an estimate for the error of the Chebyshev expansion truncated to degree $d$.

(A bonus would be an answer to the same question for $(1-x^2)^d$.)

Thanks!

Comment: The best approximation satisfies $f(-x) = (-1)^n f(x)$, so it is enough to approximate $t^{n/2}$ on $[0,1]$ by a linear combination of the first few integral or half-integral powers of $t=x^2$.  The $L^2(0,1)$ norm of the distance from $t^d$ to the span of $t^{d_i}$ can be computed exactly for any $d$ and $d_i$ for which the integrals converge (that's the key to one proof of Müntz's theorem); while that's not the $L^\infty$ norm you ask for, it should give some sense of the size of the answer.  Likewise for $(1-x^2)^d = (1-t)^d$.

Comment: Hmm.  Unfortunately this doesn't quite help me... 

The thing is, it's well known that with $d = O(\sqrt{n})$ one can get an $L^\infty$ error of $.01$ on $[0, 1-1/n] \cup \{1\}$.  What I'm really interested in is whether you can also get such small $L^\infty$ error on $[1-1/n, 1]$ too, while keeping $d$ comparable to $\sqrt{n}$.  Unfortunately, the narrowness of the interval $[1-1/n,1]$ means that looking at $L^2$ error won't tell you anything. :(

Comment: I should mention that I actually only care about the interval $[0,1]$; I just wrote $[-1,1]$ in the question because it seems to be more standard to use this interval in approximation theory.

Comment: @Ryan What is the error of $.01$, an absolute value independent of $n$?

Comment: It seems that there's some relevant context (like the "$L^\infty$ error of $.01$ on $[0, 1 - \frac1n] \cup \{1 \}$" for $d \ll \sqrt{n}$) that's "well-known" to the proposer but not to most of the readers.  Can you please outline and/or cite some of this background so we can have a better sense of what kind of answers, beyond what's already "well-known", might be of interest or use?

Comment: Sure.  Probably I shouldn't have said 'well-known'; it's somewhat well-known in theoretical computer science, let's say :)  In Example 3.11 of this paper of Nisan and Szegedy --
http://www.springerlink.com/content/p1711275700w5264/
-- they slightly manipulate the degree-$2\sqrt{n}$ Chebyshev polynomial to get a polynomial $p$ satisfying $|p(x) - 0| \leq 1/3$ for all $x \in \{0, 1/n, 2/n, \dots, 1-1/n\}$ and $|p(x) - 1| \leq 1/3$ for $x = 1$.  It's also known and not too hard that with a little more manipulation you can replace the $1/3$ by $\epsilon$ at the expense of multiplying the degree by

Comment: the small factor $O(\log(1/\epsilon))$.  Further, I'm pretty sure that if you're a little careful you can ensure $p(1) = 1$ and $|p(x)| \leq \epsilon$ for all $x \in [0, 1-1/n]$; this is with a polynomial of degree $O(\sqrt{n} \log(1/\epsilon))$.  My question is, what if you want $\epsilon$ error (in $L^\infty$) even for this last interval $[1-1/n, 1]$?  Can you get it with degree $C_\epsilon \sqrt{n}$?  Or does one require degree proportional to $n$ for $\epsilon = .01$?  Or is the tradeoff something in between?

thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Yes, it works for all $[0,1]$.  See the answers below (Andrew posted for $(1-x^2)^n$ as I was finishing the write-up for $x^n$).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For large $n$ and fixed $\epsilon > 0$ there is a polynomial of degree $d = O_\epsilon(\sqrt{n})$ that uniformly approximates $x^n$ to within $\epsilon$ on all of $[-1,+1]$.  The polynomial can be taken to be the truncated Čebyšev expansion of $x^n$, as the original proposer (OP) suggested.  As $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, the $O_\epsilon$ constant grows only as $(\log(\epsilon^{-1}))^{1/2}$; for example, $d = 2.576 \sqrt{n}$ suffices to get $\epsilon = .01$ if I computed correctly.

The OP wrote that truncating the Čebyšev expansion will give the correct $L^\infty$ distance to within a log factor.  I don't see *a priori* why this should be, but fortunately the coefficients of the expansion of $x^n$ in Čebyšev polynomials turn out to be elementary and familiar enough to work with explicitly.

It will be convenient to define $T_k(x)$ for all $k \in \bf Z$ as the polynomial such that $T_k(\cos u) = \cos ku$.  Then $T_{-k} = T_k$ is a polynomial of degree $|k|$ satisfying $|T_k(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x\in [-1,+1]$.  Now the Čebyšev expansion of $x^n$ is simply
$$
x^n = \frac1{2^n} \sum_{m=0}^n {n \choose m} T_{2m-n}(x),
$$
which can be checked by writing $x = \cos u = \frac12(e^{iu}+e^{-iu})$ and $T_k(x) = \frac12(e^{iku}+e^{-iku})$.  So the coefficients form a binomial distribution, and truncating at degree $d$ eliminates only the tail of the distribution past $d^2/n$ standard deviations.  Since each $|T_{2m-n}(x)| \leq 1$, this tail also bounds the truncation error for all $x \in [-1,+1]$, and we conclude that this error can be brought below any positive $\epsilon$ by making $d$ a large enough multiple of $\sqrt{n}$, as claimed.

This might not be the optimal $L^\infty$ approximation (except for $d=n-1$, when its optimality is the result of Čebyšev that you quoted), but it's not too far, because it *is* the best $L^2$ approximation with respect to the Čebyšev measure $\pi^{-1} dx/ \sqrt{1-x^2}$, and the $L^\infty$ distance is at least as large as the $L^2$ distance.  The $L^2$ distance can be computed from the sums of the squares of the coefficients in the tail.

Much the same technique should work for $(1-x^2)^n$; indeed I see that while I was writing this Andrew posted an answer for $(1-x^2)^n$ that looks very similar to what I did for $x^n$.

Comment: Thanks Noam!  The fact that the Chebyshev truncation gives best error up to a log factor is a theorem I read somewhere (maybe Rivlin's book?).

Answer (score 5):

For $P_n(x)=(1-x^2)^n$, large $n$ and $a>0$ it's possible to produce a polinomial of degree $a\sqrt{2n}$ with difference in $L_\infty$ less than $C(1-\mathrm{erf}\;a)$, where $C$ is an absolute constant. Taking any positive  sequence $a(n)\to+\infty$ as $n\to\infty$ leads to $L_\infty$ norm converging to zero. For large $a$ we have $1-\mathrm{erf}\;a \sim e^{-a^2}/(a\sqrt{\pi})\;$. So to obtain the uniform $\varepsilon$ estimate on $[0,1]$  the degree $\sim C(\log \varepsilon^{-1})^{1/2}\sqrt n\ $ is enough.

Namely, consider $P_n$ on the segment $[-1,1]$. Let $x=\sin y$. Now it is enough to approximate the function 
$$
\sin^{2n}y =\sum_{k=0}^n c_n^k\cos 2ky
$$
on $[0,2\pi]$ by suitable trigonometric polynomials. Here $c_n^0=\frac1{4^{n}}{2n\choose n}$, $c_n^k =(-1)^{n-k}\frac1{2^{2n-1}}{2n\choose n+k}$, $k=1,\ldots,n$. For degree $2m<2n$ we'll take the polynomial 
$$
Q_{2m}(x)=\sum_{k=0}^m c_n^k\cos 2ky.
$$
Then the $L_\infty$ norm 
$$
\|P_{2n}-Q_{2m}\| {} \le \sum_{k=m+1}^{n}  |c_n^k|=\frac1{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}{2n\choose n+k}.
$$

The last sum can be easily estimated since it is exactly the sum of the tails in the Bernoulli distribution with probability $p=1/2$ and $2n$ independent  trials. For $m=[ a\sqrt{2n}]$ and large $n$ by the central limit theorem it is equal approximately to $2(1-\mathrm{erf}\;a)$. From here the above estimates follow.

Comment: Very nice answer, but is there any reference for any of this?

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing that's easier to derive from scratch (now that the method is known) than to find in the literature...

Comment: @Igor It's all straightforward calculations here.

Comment: Erm, the sum in the last displayed formula is the bulk, not the tail, so it doesn't even tend to $0$...

Comment: OK, makes sense now :)

Answer (score 2):

Only a comment, but too long to fit in the comments section:

You sound unsure of the result for $d=n-1$.  See the end of the page http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html.  This gives the result, but there is a nice explanation in Acton's book *Numerical Methods That Work*: The Chebyshev polynomial

$T_n(x)=2^{n-1}x^n+$terms in $x^{n-2}$ and lower

is known to have $Int(n/2)$ minima of $-1$ and $Int((n-1)/2)$ maxima of $+1$ in the range $[-1,1]$.  So, rearrange:

$x^n = 2^{-(n-1)}[T_n(x)-($terms in $x^{n-2}$ and lower$)]$

and you have an $(n-2)$-order polynomial approximation of $x^n$, with an error that oscillates between $\pm2^{-(n-1)}$ the correct number of times, which is therefore optimal.

Acton's book is a pleasure to read in any case, and will also lead you through Remes's algorithm if you want to generate minimax approximations for reasonably small $n$.  You might want to search for this algorithm (if you don't know it already).  For approximating polynomials (or just powers), search for "economization of series".  I think there's actually pseudocode of an algorithm for it in the first edition of Oldham and Spanier's  *An Atlas of Functions*.  This is another lovely book, so long as you check the errata -- see http://www.trentu.ca/chemistry/oldham/AAOF.html.  The second edition is better in some ways, but much less useful for algorithms.